# Making UIScrollView with an UIImageView scale content automatically using Swift, autolayout and SnapKit

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout, snapkit

I have a view controller set up in Interface Builder with the following view structure:

```
- UIView
   * UIScrollView
      * UIImageView
```

I want to assign an image to `UIImageView` so, that the scroll view (and it's content size) will adopt the same *width* than in the image and automatically calculate the *height* of the content size according to the image aspect ratio. (This makes the image vertically scrollable inside the `UIScrollView`.)

I'm using Swift and Interface Builder + SnapKit for managing autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make the constraints using SnapKit in the following way:

- In Interface Builder, select the view controller and create all missing constraints by selecting **Editor** / **Resolve Auto Layout Issues** / **Add Missing Constraints**
- Manually select all generated constraints and select **Placeholder** / **Remove at build time** from **Attributes Inspector**
- Assign `UIScrollView` and `UIImageView` outlets to the view controller
- Assign an image to the `UIImageView`

Then implement the view controller as follows:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(view)
        }

        let ratio = imageView.image!.size.height / imageView.image!.size.width
        imageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(0.0)
            make.bottom.equalTo(scrollView.snp.bottom)
            make.width.equalTo(view.snp.width)
            make.height.equalTo(scrollView.snp.width).multipliedBy(ratio)
        }
    }
}
```